# Multiple paperclip upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I've read all the answers and still code does not work for some reason.

Here are my models:

Campaign:

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, reject_if: lambda { |t| t['picture'].nil? }
end
```

Picture:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :campaign
  has_attached_file :banner, styles: { small: "150x150>", large: "320x240>" }
  do_not_validate_attachment_file_type :banner
end
```

Controller:
Default CRUD scaffold controller except:

```
 def new
  @campaign = Campaign.new
  4.times {@campaign.pictures.build}
 end

 def edit
  @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
  4.times { @campaign.pictures.build }
 end

 def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:title, :pictures_attributes => [:banner, :banner_content_type, :banner_file_name, :tempfile, :banner_file_size, :banner_updated_at, :_destroy])
 end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @campaign, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |builder| %>
<% if builder.object.new_record? %>

<p>
  <%= builder.label :banner, "Image File" %>
  <%= builder.file_field :banner, multiple: true %>
</p>

<% end %>
<% end %>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Also here's what server says:

[Console Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVmVj.jpg)

But why, it seems I've permitted it in controller.

Comment: did you get this error when submitting?if so what's the `update` action like?

Comment: @kasperite I don't get any errors when I create a campaign. But pictures I attach just don't go to the database, it's empty.

Comment: it will be useful to see full error log, can you paste it in question?

Comment: @kasperite sure I've updated the post. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YVmVj.jpg